# How to get html signature when sedning mail on mobile

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-server

I have a customer who sometimes use IBM traveler to send emails. There have now been a request to allow personal mail signatures containing formatted text / html and logo in the signature also when sending mail from mobile.

When sending email from IOS the signature seem to only accept plain text. also tried webmail and verse mobile app

is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a server addon to add the signature ON the server. This cannot be done without additional software.

Comment: what do you mean by server addon? is there 3rd party products for this?

Comment: Yes. There is an HTML Disclaimer that you can append with default Domino settings, but that one is NOT personalized (aka same disclaimer for everybody). If you need a personalized disclaimer, you need to buy a 3rd party product.